# Add extra information into a field in MongoDB - API RESTfull

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, rest

I am creating a database of animals. For each product I have stored in my database information as follows::

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("55489125dadf65e30969d6d3"),
  "codAnimal": "100001",
  "animalData": {
    "EN": {
      "name": "Monkey",
      "description": "The monkey lives in the jungle"
    }
  }
}
```

Then I want to add extra information in the same animal, but in another language, using tags, something like this I would like to add for each language:

```
    "ES": {
      "name": "Mono",
      "description": "El mono vive en la selva"
    }
```

The result should be this:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("55489125dadf65e30969d6d3"),
  "codAnimal": "100001",
  "animalData": {
    "EN": {
      "name": "Monkey",
      "description": "The monkey lives in the jungle"
    },
    "ES": {
      "name": "Mono",
      "description": "El mono vive en la selva"
    }
  }
}
```

But I do not know what way I can do this, and I do not know if this is possible. I'm working with a RESTfull API Nodo.js and Angularjs.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using the [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set) operator with an **[update](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update)**:

```
var query = {
    "_id": ObjectId("55489125dadf65e30969d6d3"),
    "codAnimal": "100001"
},
update = {
    "$set": {    
        "animalData.ES": {
            "name": "Mono",
            "description": "El mono vive en la selva"
        }            
    }
};

db.collection.update(query, update, {"upsert": true});
```

-- **UPDATE** -- (untested)

To send this data through a RESTful API, you might need to consider changing your document schema so that the animalData info becomes an embedded subdocument which would be easier to query i.e.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("55489125dadf65e30969d6d3"),
    "codAnimal": "100001",
    "animalData": [
        {
            "language_id": "EN",
            "name": "Monkey",
            "description": "The monkey lives in the jungle"
        },
        {
            "language_id": "ES",
            "name": "Mono",
            "description": "El mono vive en la selva"
        }
    ]
}
```

Your server.js file should basically have this kind of set up where you need to define the database schema with Mongoose. A schema is just a representation of your data in MongoDB. This is where you can enforce a certain field to be of particular type. A field can also be required, unique, contain only certain characters:

```
// server.js
var express = require("express"),
    mongoose = require("mongoose"),
    _ = require('lodash');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test') // This connects to a MongoDB db called test

var animalSchema = {
    "codAnimal": String,
    "animalData": [{
         "language_id": String,
         "name": String,
         "description": String
     }]
}

var Animal = mongoose.model('Animal', animalSchema, 'animal')

var app = express();

/**
 * Update animal details
 */
app.put('/api/animals/:id', function (req, res){
    var animal = req.animal;
    animal = _.extend(animal, req.body);

    animal.update({ _id: animal.id },
        { 
            "$addToSet": { 
                 "animalData": {
                     "language_id": req.body.lang,
                     "name": req.body.name,
                     "description": req.body.description 
                 }
            } 
        },
        function(err) {
            if (err) {
                return res.send(400, {
                     message: getErrorMessage(err)
                });
            } else {
                res.jsonp(animal);
            }
    });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

The above is only a general barebone structure of how the API put operation would look like. There are plenty of tutorials around the web that offer in-depth code on setting up a MEAN stack app, among others you could check out **[First API with Node.js, Express and MongoDB](https://egghead.io/lessons/nodejs-first-api-with-node-js-express-and-mongodb)**, **[Create a TV Show Tracker using AngularJS, Node.js and MongoDB](http://sahatyalkabov.com/create-a-tv-show-tracker-using-angularjs-nodejs-and-mongodb/)**, **[Write a todo list with Express and MongoDB](http://dreamerslab.com/blog/en/write-a-todo-list-with-express-and-mongodb/)** and **[MEAN.JS - Full-Stack JavaScript Using MongoDB, Express, AngularJS, and Node.js](https://github.com/meanjs/mean)**

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I have a question, for sending this information through a PUT my RESTfull? how do you think I should?

Comment: @chridam wouldn't this replace the value of `animalData` with the new object instead of appending it as OP wanted ? The correct way would be to use `animalData.ES` (dot notation) for `$set`.

Comment: @thegreenogre You are correct, I've updated my asnwer to reflect this. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: @chridam but, for sending this information through a PUT my RESTfull? how do you think I should?

Comment: @Manu I've updated the answer to include the necessary part though your question seems to be a bit broad, i.e. there are too many possible answers for it. It could be really helpful if you could add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.